# Transition set to none with BS4 4.3.1 CDN

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using the following BS4 verison 4.3.1 CDN in my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I have the following html card component applied to my page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#flex-content" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="flex-content" id="flex-content-link" class="d-block">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-lg float-right"></i>
                <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
            </a>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <div id="flex-content" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="flex-content-link" style="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Some basic content</p>
                <p>Some basic content</p>
                <p>Some basic content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript applied to page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Yet, the following css from the CDN overrides the main transition effect when I attempt to toggle (show/hide) my elements:

```
  @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .collapsing {
      transition: none; } }
```

...over the transition source as shown below...

```
.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.35s ease; }
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Just tested your code on macOS Safari with Reduced Motion enabled via accessibility panel and it works as expected. Transition is smooth when disabled and instantaneous when enabled. Have you confirmed you're testing it in a browser that supports the declaration and that reduced motion is enabled?

Comment: thank you so much for confirming. im going to check my chrome developer tools settings and see if there is anything from my broswer thats causing the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity I've just checked it in Chrome (again, macOS) and it's honoring reduced motion when it is toggled via the Accessibility panel.